# How to calculate next date(days months and year) based on provided number of days in java?

Tags: java, date

Iam trying to calculate new date based on  provided  no. of days to base date(i.e current date or any specific date).
Linux shell can do by
date -d "2020-10-19 30 days"

2020-10-19  is base date
30 is new date after 30 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        final LocalDate nowPlus30Days = now.plusDays(30);
        System.out.println(nowPlus30Days);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Is it my duty to check for duplicate questions before answering?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326622/is-it-my-duty-to-check-for-duplicate-questions-before-answering)